# How do I automate the batch processing of a Mac Terminal zip file recovery command?

Tags: macos, terminal, batch-processing, zip

I have a folder (Mac OS X Yosemite) of zip files numbering 1 through 1822 that I would like to run the following Terminal command on each in a batch:

```
zip -FF ***x***.zip --out recovered-***x***.zip
```

where x is the number of the file, 1 to 1822, and there are missing numbered files/gaps.

How would I best automate this?

Answer (score 0):

I found something that worked well enough for my purposes:

```
for file in *.zip; do
    zip -FF $file --out recovered$file
done
```